# Playa - If no parent conditional

Tags: playa, zoo-visitor

I'm using Zoo Visitor and Playa.

I have tried lots of different conditionals for "if no playa parent" to show the title of a parent entry for a Zoo Visitor member.

I'd like to display something else if there is no parent. However, can't seem to find a technique that works. Techniques 1, 2 and 3 all print out the parent title, but they don't print out the else condition.

Any solutions or ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

**1)**

```
{exp:zoo_visitor:details}
{exp:playa:parents channel="channel_name"} 

{if count == 1}

    {title}

{if:else}

    Do something else

{/if}

{/exp:playa:parents}
{/exp:zoo_visitor:details}
```

**2)**

```
{exp:zoo_visitor:details}
{exp:playa:parents channel="channel_name"} 

    {if count > 0}

        {title}

    {if:else}

        Do something else

 {/if}

{/exp:playa:parents}
{/exp:zoo_visitor:details}
```

**3**

```
{exp:zoo_visitor:details}
{exp:playa:parents channel="channel_name"} 

{if {exp:playa:total_parents} > 0}

    {title}

{if:else}

    Do something else

{/if}

{/exp:playa:parents}
{/exp:zoo_visitor:details}
```

**4)** Doesn't even echo out the title

```
{exp:zoo_visitor:details}
{exp:playa:parents channel="channel_name"} 

     {if total_parents == 1}

            {title}

    {if:else}

            Do something else

   {/if}

{/exp:playa:parents}
{/exp:zoo_visitor:details}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
{if total_results > 0}
    {title}
{/if}

{if no_parents}
    Something else
{/if}
```

Comment: Legend! That worked perfectly. Thank you for your time!